# WebView doesn't show up Icons in Google Map

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, webview

I am trying to load a web page with tracking details and Google map with marker icons in a web view using the plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview). The map is not showing up marker icons in android mobiles. If I load the same url using browser component it is showing up the icons but i need it to be working on webview as well.Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  Trying to find the icon path for use in Google Maps on Android with webview also.

Comment: No I couldn’t find a solution for this